# How to style asp.net dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, css, html-select

You may feel it is a repeated question, but I have a Asp:DropDownList which needs to be styled like the below picture.

I browsed through Google and some sites (mentioned in Stack), but I couldn't get the expected outcome.

Can anybody help me in this?

[image]

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Search for Dropkick.js/dropkick.css files it may help you to design custom style to your dropdownlist in asp.net

Comment: Nope, I tried dropkick.No use of it.My total design collapses of it.But no change to dropdownlist..

Comment: http://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2013/12/aspnet-dropdownlist-change-arrow-image.html

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try the following code

**HTML**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="120px" BackColor="#F6F1DB" ForeColor="#7d6754" Font-Names="Andalus" CssClass="ddl">
    <asp:ListItem Text="DEPART FROM"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**CSS**
**EDIT**

```
<style type="text/css">
        .ddl
        {
            border:2px solid #7d6754;
            border-radius:5px;
            padding:3px;
            -webkit-appearance: none; 
            background-image:url('Images/Arrowhead-Down-01.png');
            background-position:88px;
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            text-indent: 0.01px;/*In Firefox*/
            text-overflow: '';/*In Firefox*/
        }
</style>
```

Check the screenshot which I got in Chrome also I am attaching the dropdown down arrow image(Arrowhead-Down-01.png).Hope this helps you.

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Arrowhead-Down-01.png**

[image]

Comment: Arun Bertil,Thanks for your effort.I am happy with it.But its working only in chrome,not in IE10,mozilla 23..Is there any make over for that..

Comment: Again thanks..I tried "-moz-appearance:none"..But it dint work...U did it..Why the heck IE is making a mess in all concerns..

Comment: yes...there is issue in IE...let me chk if there is any workaround...:):)...happy to know it helped u..

Comment: i hvae got a html select workaround which works in all browsers...with the way you want is it ok..then I will post?

Comment: Yes please go ahead..BUt make sure dont remove the current one,post that along with this..

Answer (score 5):

HTML select solution

**HTML**

```
<div class="styled-select">
  <select>
    <option>DEPART FROM</option>
    <option>DEPART TO</option>
    <option>DEPART AWAY</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
  .styled-select {
   width: 150px;
   height: 30px;
   overflow: hidden;
   background: url('Images/Arrowhead-Down-01.png') no-repeat right #F6F1DB;
   border: 2px solid #7d6754;
   border-radius: 5px;
   }

   .styled-select select {
   background: transparent;
   width: 180px;
   padding: 3px;
   font-size: 16px;
   line-height: 1;
   border: 0;
   border-radius: 0;
   height: 30px;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   font-family:Andalus;
   color:#7d6754;
   }
```