# List Box Format (Design/Color/3d)

Tags: css, html

I been looking over the web and can't seem to find where to change the formatting for my list box. Is it possible to change the color of the box and give it more of a sleek design.

Below is a general list box code any design changes (change color/design/boarder of list box) would be appreciated it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

 <H2>List Box</H2>
<select size="4">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Styling the `select` tag has been covered thoroughly on this thread [how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

the  element has styles on the browser itself. every browser has a different style for this element. if you want to override them, use reset.css or normalize.css

good read- http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

update:- but, you can always change the basics. have a look :- http://tympanus.net/Development/SelectInspiration/
http://cssdeck.com/labs/styling-select-box-with-css3

Answer (score 0):

Hey Please Go Through the below link. This may help.

[How to style asp.net dropdownlist - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952736/how-to-style-asp-net-dropdownlist)

Here is another link, this helps a lot and has a lot more freedom.

[Kendo UI Dropdown List Custom Template](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/template)

Edit :

Here is a fiddle for you. with a different color for the drop down list [Dropdown List with color](http://jsfiddle.net/zNLNy/1312/)

```
<div>
Sample Kendo UI Drop Down List
<select id="fruit">
            <option>Apple</option>
            <option>Orange</option>
            <option>Grapes</option>
            <option>Strawberry</option>
        </select>
```

```
$("#fruit").kendoDropDownList();
```

There are plenty of options you can play with. Please refer this link http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/themebuilder/

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Is it possible to have the list box be dark blue?

Comment: @Nguyenal07 : You can change the color according to your wish. Please see the edit.

Comment: how do i get the code for "TabStrip" I'm confused. Can you show me an example? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you have the change the color of the strip that is being currently highlighted?